# Batch file timer and duration calculator

Tags: batch-file

I made this Batch file that works as a timer for two events and loops through them again and again indefinitely (until you kill it). It also calculate the time spent in the first event plus the time elapsed till the second event is started. It post the output into a text file.
The timer works just fine, but the duration calculation is iffy sometimes (it works ok for most of the time though).

**Issues:**

1. if the timer is started between the times 2 am (and may be 12 am I haven't tested it at that time) to 9:59 am, the duration is not gonna be calculated. I get the last stopping time of the first event posted to the text file twice, instead.
2. Sometimes, when I run the timer in the morning, especially really early in the morning like around 5 or 6 am, the duration will be calculated 00:00:00. even though there was a starting and stopping time. The funny thing is, the timer works just fine most of the time and it only create this problem randomly.
3. Is it possible to skip the timer for one event and continue to the next without terminating the batch job? if Yes, how to do that? please post an example code.

Would someone highlight where the code is wrong and post the fix, pretty please.

And for whoever out there who wants to close this post just because he thinks its not important, not useful, etc.., please fix my issues first or let someone do that before you close the post.

I spent hours and hours trying to fix these issues before attempting to make a post here, so please have some understanding.

**Here is the code:**

```
@ECHO off

MODE CON:COLS=46 LINES=9

echo --------------------------------- >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

echo. >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

echo %date% >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

set counter=0

set TST=0

:1

@echo off

setlocal

rem The format of %TIME% is HH:MM:SS,CS for example 23:59:59,99
set STARTTIME=%TIME%

@echo off 

set /a counter=counter+1

set /a TST=TST+%duration%

rem now break the centiseconds down to hors, minutes, seconds and the remaining centiseconds
set /A TSTH=%TST% / 360000
set /A TSTM=(%TST% - %TSTH%*360000) / 6000
set /A TSTS=(%TST% - %TSTH%*360000 - %TSTM%*6000) / 100
set /A TSTHS=(%TST% - %TSTH%*360000 - %TSTM%*6000 - %TSTS%*100)

rem some formatting
if %TSTH% LSS 10 set TSTH=0%TSTH%
if %TSTM% LSS 10 set TSTM=0%TSTM%
if %TSTS% LSS 10 set TSTS=0%TSTS%
if %TSTHS% LSS 10 set TSTHS=0%TSTHS%

echo. >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

echo Total Time: %TSTH%:%TSTM%:%TSTS% Plus >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt
echo Started on: %time%  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt


color f0

cls 

:hour

set hour=1                            

:min

set min=0

:second

set second=0

:countit

cls                                                          

echo                  Main Event
echo            %date%
echo.
echo   %min%    Minutes  
echo   %sec%    Seconds
echo        Hours #    %counter%
echo        Total Time: %TSTH%:%TSTM%:%TSTS%

set /a sec="%sec%-1"

if %sec%==-1 set /a min="%min%-1"
if %sec%==-1 set /a sec="59"
if %min%==-1 set /a hour="%hour%-1"
if %min%==-1 set /a min="59"
if %hour%==-1 goto 2

ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL

goto countit

:2

start "" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Timer file\1.mp3"

echo.

pause>nul

echo Are You Sure?

pause>nul

cls

echo Okay then, Ready..

Pause>nul

@echo off

echo stopped on: %time%  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

rem output as time
echo STARTTIME: %STARTTIME%
echo ENDTIME:    %ENDTIME%

rem convert STARTTIME and ENDTIME to centiseconds
set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)

set /A ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%ENDTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%ENDTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%ENDTIME:~9,2%-100)

rem calculating the duratyion is easy
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

rem now break the centiseconds down to hors, minutes, seconds and the remaining centiseconds
set /A DURATIONH=%DURATION% / 360000
set /A DURATIONM=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000) / 6000
set /A DURATIONS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000) / 100
set /A DURATIONHS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000 - %DURATIONS%*100)

rem some formatting
if %DURATIONH% LSS 10 set DURATIONH=0%DURATIONH%
if %DURATIONM% LSS 10 set DURATIONM=0%DURATIONM%
if %DURATIONS% LSS 10 set DURATIONS=0%DURATIONS%
if %DURATIONHS% LSS 10 set DURATIONHS=0%DURATIONHS%

rem outputing
echo Duration is %DURATIONH%:%DURATIONM%:%DURATIONS% >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\Progress.txt

cls

:4

color e0

cls

:hour

set hour=0                           

:min

set min=10

:sec

set sec=0

:continue

cls                                                             

echo                   Break...
echo            %date%
echo.                                                           
echo   %min%    Minutes  
echo   %sec%    Seconds
echo        Hours #    %counter%
echo        Total Time: %TSTH%:%TSTM%:%TSTS%

set /a sec="%sec%-1"

if %sec%==-1 set /a min="%min%-1"
if %sec%==-1 set /a sec="59"
if %min%==-1 set /a hour="%hour%-1"
if %min%==-1 set /a min="59"
if %hour%==-1 goto 3

ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL

goto continue

:3

start "" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Timer file\2.mp3"

echo.

pause>nul

echo Are You Sure?

pause>nul

cls

echo Okay then, Ready..

Pause>nul

cls

goto 1
```

Comment: I don't get it! nobody has an answer for these issues?! Please guys, one of you solve it pleasssssse.

Comment: @DavidPostill You sir seem like a king on this forum. Would you possibly help me out here, please.

Comment: @Gynnad I used some formula similar to the script that you once posted. but the time is not being calculated after midnight. I'm experimenting with what's being posted on this link but no luck so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605522/print-time-in-a-batch-fil%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be-milliseconds. Could you please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it. Thanks